# How to get the Unix timestamp of a specific time last month

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a donations table in a MySQL database in which I store - you guessed it - donation records. Now, I display how much has been donated each month on my website. I need to get the donation total for this month. The billing period rolls over on the 9th of each month for me - so...

`SELECT sum(amount) from donations where timestamp`

`timestamp` here is the Unix timestamp for when a PayPal donation was made.

I can't go in and change the query each month. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the unix timestamp to a date using `from_unixtime()`.  Then you can subtract 9 days and convert to a year/month format and aggregate to get the value for each month.

```
select date_format(date_sub(from_unixtime(timestamp), interval -9 day), '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       sum(amount)
from donations
group by date_format(date_sub(from_unixtime(timestamp), interval -9 day), '%Y-%m')
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: Fantastic! I've learned something new today. Thank you for your assistance, and have a wonderful day. ^^

Comment: This isn't actually working; it's returning the wrong values. :/

Comment: @AustinBurk . . . (1) How is it returning the wrong values?  (2) Why would it have stopped working in the past month?  Presumably, it did work when you accepted the answer.

Comment: I think it's because it didn't reset on the 9th, and showed more donations than it should have. I got it working nicely.